# Правильно ли включать в тест зависимый тест?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, тестирование, зависимости

Например, хочу протестировать добавление и удаление элемента из списка.

```py
import unittest

class ListTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        self.l = list()

    def test_add():
        self.l.add(42)
        self.assertEqual(l[0] == 42)

    def test_del():
        self.l.add(42)
        self.assertEqual(l[0] == 42)  # Допустим ли этот тест?
        del l[0]
        self.assertEqual(len(l) == 0)
```

Допустимо ли добавлять указанный ассерт или он уже есть в `test_add`? С другой стороны, добавление должно быть и если оно неправильно работает, то удаление нет смысла тестировать дальше. Если в будущем тест добавления удалится, то всё продолжит работать с этим ассертом. Может в таком случае лучше использовать `expect` а не `assert`?

Comment: По-моему правильнее для тестирования добавления элемента в пустой список использовать `self.assertIn(42, l)` и соответственно для удаления `self.assertNotIn(42, l)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Все аргументы говорят - нет, не нужно.**

Из общих соображений, стоит помнить что это *юнит*-тесты. Т.е. тестирование единиц функционала. Разумно исходить из общего предположения, что все остальное работает корректно (конструктор объекта, передача аргументов, семантика языка, компилятор, ОС, память, ЦП, электроны, и т.п.). Вы тестируете конкретные вещи:
Есть тест на добавление - он тестирует добавление.
Есть тест на удаление - он тестирует удаление.

Было бы странно в каждом из тестов тестировать ВСЁ нижележащие. В то же время, желательно, чтобы у вас были покрыты тестами все составные части - если добавление сломано, то соседний тест это покажет. Итоговая цель - прохождение 100% тестов, а не "95% сойдет" )

Ещё, кстати, вспомните и о принципе DRY - дублирование штука нехорошая, и о SRP - тестирование удаления должно отвечать за тестирование удаления.

Еще один момент - тестированию удаления не должно быть дела до того как элементы попадают в список (добавлением ли, десериализацией ли, методом ГСЧ списка, итд).

Answer (score 0):

В тесте удаления вообще не нужно использовать другие функции, а нужно использовать уже готовый список или что там у вас за тип данных.

Comment: А где мне его взять, если он нетривиально составляется? Да и даже в данном случае мы всё равно тестируем конструирование листа тогда. И если есть метод `test_construct`, то тоже будет пересечение ассертов.

Comment: То что готовый к тестированию список надо откуда-то брать, звучит неплохо, но городить свой отдельный сетап для каждого случая (вот тут для удаления, вот там для сортировки, вот сям для сериализации, вот этам для еще чего-то) несколько накладно, при том, что это все равно эти сетапы получаются жестко связаны (coupled) с соответствующими тестами. Поэтому, имхо вполне разумно готовить сетап и тестировать в одном месте. А вот общий Setup/Teardown это уже DRY )